# How to have a background thread update UI several times with delays between the updates?

Tags: android, multithreading

I want to have a thread that generates the level and then with the new information from the calculations to update the UI several times with delays between them. useHandler() is called in the onCreate of the MainActivity:

```
Handler mHandler;
public void useHandler() {
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
}
private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        calculateLevel();
        updateUI();
        //delay
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        updateUI2();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        updateUI3();
        //then start over again
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
    }
};
```

The problem with what I wrote is that it doesn't seem to update the UI when using:

imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.Blah);

I also don't know if this code runs on a separate thread. What's the best way to do all of this?

Comment: hint1: *useHandler() is called in the onCreate* => the handler is created on main thread => runable posted to the handler will be run on main thread ... hint2: Thread.sleep is always a bad choice... why don't you use the postDelayed again?

Comment: Then how do I make it run on a separate thread. I'll change it to postDelayed if it matters, not really the issue though.

Comment: here is an example ... you have 2 handlers ... one is from main thread the second is on new handlerthread ... https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/eaf75cf244df4d2f2ee6 (Thread.sleep is just as an example of long running stuff like fx your calculateLevel)